# $A$={a, b, c}. Does {$A$}={$A$, a, b, c}?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ be a set with elements a,b,c. Would {*A*} = {*A*, a, b, c}?

We say $A$ = $B$ iff (X ∈ $A$ ⇒ X ∈ $B$) & (X ∈ $B$ ⇒ X ∈ $A$).

My reasoning is that X $\in$ {*A*} $\Rightarrow$ X $\in$ {$A$, a, b, c} since *A* is in both sets, and X $\in$ {$A$, a, b, c} $\Rightarrow$ X $\in$ {$A$} since $A$ is in both sets, and a,b,c $\in$ $A$ $\rightarrow$ a,b,c $\in$ {$A$}, thus making the two sets equal.

Comment: Your second step $X\in\{A,a,b,c\} \Rightarrow X\in \{A\}$ is wrong. Consider the case $X=a$. We have $a\in A$ but $a\notin\{A\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second part of your argument is incorrect, since $a \in A$ does not imply that $a \in \{A\}$. The set $\{A\}$ is a *singleton*, that is, contains only one element, no matter what the size of $A$ is.